# Падения при использовании SAX парсера в Java

Tags: java, sax, парсер

Необходимо распарсить сайт типа Avito или Gorod55. Когда парсеру скармливается адрес сайта - обязательно вылетает какая-то из ошибок. Пример - попытка парсинга gorod55:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse("*тут адрес gorod55(репутация не позволила добавить ссылку)*", new SiteSaxParser());
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: *тут адрес gorod55(репутация не позволила добавить ссылку)*; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 17; Attribute name "itemscope" associated with an element type "html" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:274)
    at com.aleksey.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: Ну, HTML не обязательно является валидным XML. XML-парсер по идее и не обязан корректно обрабатывать HTML.

Comment: Кроме того, вытаскивать информацию с чужого сайта, не пользуясь официальным API, плохо. (А если API нету, то ещё хуже.) Вам об этом никто не говорил?

Comment: Дело в том, что задача стоит именно распарсить html-ку

Comment: Ну так не используйте для этого XML-парсер. Он для этого не предназначен. Если вам поставили задачу распарсить HTML при помощи XML-парсера, скажите, что это невозможно.

Comment: Чем же тогда парсить html?

Comment: Например, HTML-парсером?

Comment: Хорошо, перефразирую. 1) Является ли SAX-парсер парсером html? Или только xml? 2) Если нет - какой парсер конкретно использовать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2168610/276994

Comment: Пробовал jsoup, невкусно. Надеюсь, это не единственный вариант:)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка указывает что элемент html содержит атрибут itemscope без значения. Что не валидно для классического XML.

т.е.

```
<html itemscope ...>
```

А ожидается конструкция типа

```
<html itemscope="value" ...>
```

Если ваш парсер не имеет настроек для игнорирования таких конструкций, то воспользуйтесь html-парсером, например [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Так же, наличие атрибута **itemscope** может означать, что ваша страница содержит Microdata, тогда попробуйте [рекомендованный парсер](http://microformats.org/wiki/microdata).